# App Compact v7 jar file not created in bin folder

Tags: android

I am getting an error saying that

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The container `'Android Dependencies'` references non existing library `'/Users/student/Documents/workspace/Rest/appcompat_v7/bin/appcompat_v7.jar'`        Build path Build Path Problem

When i see into the appcompact folder which i imported from the extra folder I cant see anything in bin folder and I also cleaned and built the project many time but the jar file is not created.

Also getting the error

```
Parsing Data for android-21 failed
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I have installed JDK 8 also.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try installing JDK 1.8 and reload Eclipse.

Comment: Installed JDK 1.8 still not working.

Answer (score 0):

appcompat_v7 is a library-project for Android 4.0+ themes.

Right click on your project -> Properties -> Android

Check if the project appcompat_v7 is checked.

[image]